# How to enable softwares sources?

Tags: 12.04

After a fresh ubuntu installation from the terminal, I mean what are the commands line I should enter to enable softwares sources such as universe/multiverse/main?

Comment: I presume you wanted a CLI-only option. If not, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You will need root/sudo privileges for this.

### The GUI Method:

Assuming you're using Unity, click the gear in the top right and click "System Settings".

You should then be presented with this window:
[image]

Then, in the bottom row, click "Software and Updates".

You'll then be presented with this window:
[image]

Now, check/uncheck the sources that you want to enable/disable. You'll be asked for ***YOUR*** password on the first click.

### The CLI (Command Line Interface) Method:

With your favorite editor, open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

It'll look something like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
## Depôt MultiSystem
## Depôt MultiSystem
deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main
```

This file is well documented (commented). To enable a source, remove the `#` in front of the line. To disable it, add a `#`.

That's it! :)